# Can I write a `concept` to accept a specific template class only?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a templated class:

```
template<Vector T>
struct diagonal_matrix;
```

Now, I want to create a `concept DiagonalMatrix` for all of templated class versions. So:

```
 DiagonalMatrix<diagonal_matrix<std::vector<double>>> == true
 DiagonalMatrix<diagonal_matrix<std::array<float, 4>>> == true
 DiagonalMatrix<diagonal_matrix<std::span<int, 10>>> == true
 DiagonalMatrix<diagonal_matrix<my::random_access_container_view<unsigned int>>> == true
 DiagonalMatrix<other_matrix> == false
```

Keep in mind that `diagonal_matrix` has a subset of `other_matrix` functionality.

Is there a way to create a `concept DiagonalMatrix` which only accepts `struct diagonal_matrix<?>` without tagging the struct with a `static constexpr bool I_am_a_diagonal_matrix = true;`?. I don't care for implementations other than `struct diagonal_matrix<?>`.

Comment: So you just want a range over arithmetic types? What is difficult about building that concept?

Comment: @NicolBolas My english is not very good. I need a concept which only accepts `struct diagonal_matrix<Vector>` where `Vector` is a concept (a really big number of accepted types).

Comment: Right. So `Vector` would be a concept that accepts the combination of "is a range" and "value_type of the range fits some concept". So what is the issue with building that?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am not sure that you understand the question and I am totally sure that I do not understand what you are saying. I am trying to write the `concept DiagonalMatrix`. `concept Vector` is completely irrelevant and it is already written.

Comment: Do you have an example why you need this concept? Because it looks like the concept is a bit redundant. The compiler generally can deduce `T` from `diagonal_matrix<T>`, and only from `diagonal_matrix<T>`.

Comment: Instead of `template <DiagonalMatrix M> auto blah(M m)`, you can have `template <Vector T> auto blah(diagonal_matrix<T> m)`. Are you wanting it for `if constexpr (DiagonalMatrix<Arg>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `diagonal_matrix` has a member aliases for all it's template parameters, you can substitute them into `diagonal_matrix<>`, then check you get what you started with.

```
template <typename M>
concept DiagonalMatrix = std::same_as<M, diagonal_matrix<typename M::vector_type>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap a plain old type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    template<typename>
    constexpr bool is_diagonal_matrix_v{};
}

template<typename T>
concept DiagonalMatrix =
    detail::is_diagonal_matrix_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

Then only types for which `detail::is_diagonal_matrix_v<>` is appropriately specialized will satisfy (i.e. it is extensible and not *strictly* limited to `diagonal_matrix<>`).

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/zMxfGcGxh)</kbd>